# what is the difference between the following 2D array declarations?

Tags: c, arrays

i cant seem to get this clear in my head especially when trying to pass the array as a parameter to a function

```
char *array[x][y];
```

and

```
char array[x][y];
```

i know both are 2D arrays and that i can pass the second declaration as a function parameter as follows:
prototype

```
void check(char**);
```

then use it as

```
void check(char array[][]) {}
```

Comment: One is a 2D array of `char`; the other is a 2D array of `char *` (character pointers).  They're quite different!

Comment: so in a `char array[x][y]` array i cant fill it with strings?

Comment: Also, 2D arrays are not passed as pointers to pointers.

Comment: With `char array[x][y]`, you could copy up to `x` strings with each string no longer than `y-1` bytes (to allow for the terminating null which isn't included in `strlen()`) into the array — using `strcpy()` or similar functions.  You could then use `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("<<%s>>\n", array[i]);` (for example) to print each of the `n` strings stored in the array (`n <= x`).

Comment: okay hanks, but what about the `char *array[x][y]` ?

Comment: Neither can be passed to `void check(char **);`, and `void check(char array[][])` is illegal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to illustrate the differences between a 2D array of pointers as an argument and a `char ***` argument.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700  // Declare strdup() on Linux
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void function_taking_2d_array(int x, int y, char *array[x][y])
{
    printf("2D array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("[%d,%d] = <<%s>>\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
}

static void function_taking_triple_pointer(int x, int y, char ***array)
{
    printf("Triple pointer:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("[%d,%d] = <<%s>>\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    char *array[x][y];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            char buffer[32];
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "fixed string [%d][%d]", i, j);
            array[i][j] = strdup(buffer);
        }
    }

    function_taking_2d_array(x, y, array);

    char **aux[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        aux[i] = array[i];

    function_taking_triple_pointer(x, y, aux);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            free(array[i][j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile cleanly with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror c3d.c -o c3d
$
```

Sample output:

```
2D array:
[0,0] = <<fixed string [0][0]>>
[0,1] = <<fixed string [0][1]>>
[0,2] = <<fixed string [0][2]>>
[0,3] = <<fixed string [0][3]>>
[1,0] = <<fixed string [1][0]>>
[1,1] = <<fixed string [1][1]>>
[1,2] = <<fixed string [1][2]>>
[1,3] = <<fixed string [1][3]>>
[2,0] = <<fixed string [2][0]>>
[2,1] = <<fixed string [2][1]>>
[2,2] = <<fixed string [2][2]>>
[2,3] = <<fixed string [2][3]>>
Triple pointer:
[0,0] = <<fixed string [0][0]>>
[0,1] = <<fixed string [0][1]>>
[0,2] = <<fixed string [0][2]>>
[0,3] = <<fixed string [0][3]>>
[1,0] = <<fixed string [1][0]>>
[1,1] = <<fixed string [1][1]>>
[1,2] = <<fixed string [1][2]>>
[1,3] = <<fixed string [1][3]>>
[2,0] = <<fixed string [2][0]>>
[2,1] = <<fixed string [2][1]>>
[2,2] = <<fixed string [2][2]>>
[2,3] = <<fixed string [2][3]>>
```

A particular point to note is that the differences between the two functions are in the function name and signature and in the identifying message — the source for the rest of the function bodies is the same.  Nevertheless, if you look at the assembler code for the two functions (assuming they weren't inlined for you), you'd see that they generate different instructions — because the types of the arguments are not the same.

Comment: well explained. Thanks.

Comment: Note the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62933/discussion-between-t-d-and-mureinik).

Answer (score 1):

The first is a two dimensional array of `char*` - i.e., `char` **pointers**, which are often used as stings in C. The second is a two dimensional array of `char`s - i.e., single characters.

Comment: okay so in order to fill a 2D array with strings i need to use a 2d array of `char` pointers ?

Comment: so far so good but how do i pass that array to a function as a parameter ?

Comment: but then can i still access it as follow: `arg[i][j]` ?

Comment: @T-D Yes. The `[]` operator works perfectly with pointers. Note that you'd need to be careful not to access indexes that are out of the array's range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62933/discussion-between-t-d-and-mureinik).

Comment: The answer is right, but alot of the stuff in these comments is not.  You can't pass `char *arr[x][y]` as a `char ***`... you'd use either `char **` and manually calculate array offsets, or `char *arr[][y]` (specifying one array dimension) to use [] indexing.

Comment: `void check(char*** arg)` can NOT accept `char *array[x][y]`. Arrays and pointers are different.